# continuously differentiable multivariable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

What does it really mean to say a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuously differentiable?

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable if $f$ is differentiable and $f':\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous..

But what is $f'$ in case of $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$..

Is it the jacobian $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}& \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}& \cdots &\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n} \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}& \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}& \cdots &\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_n} \\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_1}& \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_2}& \cdots &\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_n} \end{bmatrix}$

I could not understand how does this matrix act on $\mathbb{R}^n$..

As an example, for $f(x,y)=(xy,x+y)$ we see that jacobian is 
$\begin{bmatrix}y&x\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$.. I do not understand how do i define
 $Df: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$..

In case of derivative at a point we have $Df((a,b))=\begin{bmatrix}b&a\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ and we define

$Df(a,b)(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}b&a\\1&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}bx+ay\\x+y\end{bmatrix}$

I mean there are already variables in $Df$ and so i am getting confused how to act on $\mathbb{R}^n$.. But in case of $Df(a,b)$ there are no variables.. So, it seems to be natural.

Answer (score 11):

Given a function $f:\>\Omega\to{\mathbb R}^m$ with domain $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^n$ its derivative is a map
$$df:\quad\Omega\to{\cal L}({\mathbb R}^n,{\mathbb R}^m),\qquad x\mapsto df(x)\ .$$ The "coordinates" of $df(x)$ are the entries of the Jacobian
$$J(x):=\left[\matrix{f_{1.1}&\cdots& f_{1.n}\cr\vdots\cr f_{m.1}&\cdots& f_{m.n}\cr}\right]_x\ ,\qquad f_{i.k}(x):={\partial f_i\over\partial x_k}(x)\ .$$
The space ${\cal L}({\mathbb R}^n,{\mathbb R}^m)$ has a natural metric induced by the norm $\|A\|:=\sup_{|x|=1}|Ax|$. It so happens that the function $df$ is continuous on $\Omega$ iff all entries $f_{i.k}$ of the Jacobian are continuous on $\Omega$. This fact belongs to elementary limit geometry in ${\mathbb R}^d$ and has nothing to do with differentiation per se.

Answer (score 2):

There is a general theory of differentiation for functions between two normed space. However, you may be happy to learn that a function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuously differentiable if and only if each component $f_i \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable, for $i=1,\ldots,m$.

Comment: This seems to be reasonable idea.. but, does this have anything to do with jacobian that i have written.. Where is this $Df$ defined on?? Do we have $Df : \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Kindly help me with this

Comment: Yes, the space of matrices has a topology induced by a norm. Hence it is legitimate to speak about continuity of $Df$.

Answer (score 2):

$
\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}\,}
\newcommand{\df}{\mathrm{d}\,f}
\newcommand{\dfx}{\mathrm{d}\,f_{\x}}
\newcommand{\x}{ \vec{\mathbf{p}}}
\newcommand{\h}{ \vec{\mathbf{x}}}
\newcommand{\p}{ \vec{\mathbf{p}}}
\newcommand{\y}{ \vec{\mathbf{y}}}
\newcommand{\xz}{ \vec{\mathbf{x}}^{0}}
$
I believe that the best way to interpret Jacobian matrix is think of it as a **total derivative** of a function $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$.
In other words, $f' $ is the **best linear approximation** of $f$.
The linear approximation depends on a point at which we trying to expand $f$.

Recall the definition of differentiable function $\left( \text{ at a point } \ \x = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} x^p_1, & x^p_2, & , \dots, & x^p_n\end{smallmatrix}\right]^T\,\right)$:

> $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ is called (**totally**) **differentiable**, at a point $x_0 \in\Bbb R^n $ if there exists a *linear map*  $\dfx :  \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ such that 
>   $$
> \lim_{\x\to \y} \frac{\left\|\, f\left(\x\right) - f\left(\y\right) - \dfx  \left(\x - \y\right) \,\right\|}{\left\|\, \left(\x - \y\right) \,\right\|} = 0
> $$

In this case the *linearization* of $f$ at a point $\x$ will look like:
$$
f\left(\x + \y \right) = f\left(\x \right) + \dfx\cdot \y + R\left( \y \right)
$$
where the remainder $R\left( \y \right) = o\left( \left\|\y \right\|\right)$, i.e. $\lim_{\left\|\y \right\|\to 0} \frac{\left\|\, R\left(\y\right) \,\right\|}{\left\|\, \y \,\right\|} = 0$.

Since $\dfx: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n $  is a linear map, it can be represented as a matrix. 
Using notation
$$
\h = 
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix}, \qquad
f\left(\h\right) = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
f_1 \left(\h \right) \\
f_2 \left(\h \right) \\
\vdots \\
f_n \left(\h \right) 
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
f_1 \left(x_1,  x_2, \dots,  x_n \right) \\
f_2 \left(x_1,  x_2, \dots,  x_n \right) \\
\vdots \\
f_n \left(x_1,  x_2, \dots,  x_n \right) 
\end{bmatrix}, 
$$
the total derivative of $f$ can  be expressed as Jacobian matrix:
$$ 
\dfx =\frac{\mathrm{D}\,f\left(\h \right)}{\mathrm{D}\,\h}\bigg\lvert_{\h = \x} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1\left(\h \right) }{\partial x_1} \big\lvert_{\h = \x} & 
\frac{\partial f_1\left(\h \right) }{\partial x_2} \big\lvert_{\h = \x} & 
\cdots &
\frac{\partial f_1\left(\h \right) }{\partial x_n}  \big\lvert_{\h = \x}
\\
\frac{\partial f_2\left(\h \right) }{\partial x_1} \big\lvert_{\h = \x} & 
\frac{\partial f_2\left(\h \right) }{\partial x_2} \big\lvert_{\h = \x} & 
\cdots &
\frac{\partial f_2\left(\h \right) }{\partial x_n}  \big\lvert_{\h = \x}
\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots 
\\
\frac{\partial f_n\left(\h \right) }{\partial x_1} \big\lvert_{\h = \x} & 
\frac{\partial f_n\left(\h \right) }{\partial x_2} \big\lvert_{\h = \x} & 
\cdots &
\frac{\partial f_n\left(\h \right) }{\partial x_n}  \big\lvert_{\h = \x} 
\end{bmatrix}
\label{*}\tag{*}
$$

You have to keep in mind that  strictly speaking the derivative $\dfx$ is defined only at a certain point $\x\in \Bbb R^n$, and that **every entry**  in the matrix $\eqref{*}$ is a **constant**.

Therefore the Jacobian matrix can act on a vector $\y \in \Bbb R^n$, and the result will also be a vector in $\Bbb R^n$: 
$$
\dfx \cdot \y  = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1\left(\h \right) }{\partial x_1} \big\lvert_{\h = \x} & 
\frac{\partial f_1\left(\h \right) }{\partial x_2} \big\lvert_{\h = \x} & 
\cdots &
\frac{\partial f_1\left(\h \right) }{\partial x_n}  \big\lvert_{\h = \x}
\\
\frac{\partial f_2\left(\h \right) }{\partial x_1} \big\lvert_{\h = \x} & 
\frac{\partial f_2\left(\h \right) }{\partial x_2} \big\lvert_{\h = \x} & 
\cdots &
\frac{\partial f_2\left(\h \right) }{\partial x_n}  \big\lvert_{\h = \x}
\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots 
\\
\frac{\partial f_n\left(\h \right) }{\partial x_1} \big\lvert_{\h = \x} & 
\frac{\partial f_n\left(\h \right) }{\partial x_2} \big\lvert_{\h = \x} & 
\cdots &
\frac{\partial f_n\left(\h \right) }{\partial x_n}  \big\lvert_{\h = \x} 
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{bmatrix}
\implies 
\dfx \cdot \y \in  \Bbb R^n
$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#The_total_derivative_as_a_linear_map

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ then continuity of $Df$ means that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that if $||u - v|| <\delta$ then $||Dfu - Dfv|| < \epsilon$.

**Edit**

Using your mapping that you have above, if we let $u = \left [ \begin{array}{c}
u_1 \\
u_2 \\
\end{array} \right ]$ and $v = \left [ \begin{array}{c}
v_1 \\
v_2\\
\end{array} \right ]$, then whenever $||u-v|| < \delta$ we would find

$$
||Dfu - Dfv|| \;\; =\;\; ||Df(u-v)|| \;\; =\;\;\left | \left | \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
y & x \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right ] \left [ \begin{array}{c}
u_1 - v_1 \\
u_2 - v_2\\
\end{array} \right ] \right | \right | \;\; =\;\; \left | \left | \; \left [ \begin{array}{c}
(u_1 - v_1)y + (u_2 - v_2)x \\
u_1 - v_1 + u_2 - v_2 \\
\end{array} \right ] \; \right | \right |
$$

which under the Euclidean norm turns into

$$
||Dfu - Dfv|| \;\; =\;\; \sqrt{[(u_1 - v_1)y + (u_2 - v_2)x]^2 + (u_1 + u_2 - v_1 - v_2)^2 } \;\; < \;\; \epsilon.
$$

Comment: Before that i would like to know $Df$ is a function from where to where..

Comment: If you are dealing solely in Euclidean spaces, then if $f:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth function, its Jacobian is (automatically) a linear mapping $Df: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: But $Df(a,b)$ we have a matrix, so, $Dfu$ has to be a matrix and not a vector... :O So, i guess $Df : \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: @pkumar You are (almost) right, but the normed space of all matrices of given dimension is isomorphic to a euclidean space of appropriate dimension (what dimension?)

Comment: @pkumar No, that's not the case.  Please see my edits above, I illustrated how it would work given the mapping you proposed.  Either way the discussion is trivial; all linear maps are continuous, hence if a function between Euclidean spaces is smooth it is automatically continuously differentiable.

Comment: Smooth means continuously differentiable no.. then what does it mean when you say smooth it is automatically continuously differentiable

Comment: @Siminore : I see that $M_n(\mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$

Comment: I have seen the edit... I thought $Df$ is a matrix with variable entries... I do not know how can $Dfu-Dfv=Df(u-v)$

Comment: @pkumar The derivative of the mapping $f$ **IS** the Jacobian matrix, hence $Df$ is a linear map.

Comment: when a matrix has real entries then it acts linearly.. but jacobian has variable entries...

Comment: @pkumar Ahh, ok.  There is a subtlety here which arises because we are in multiple dimensions.  In single-variable calculus there is only one derivative because there is only one degree of freedom in which the quantity can change.  When we extend this to multiple dimensions there infinitely many directions that our derivative can be pointing, and this gives rise to *directional derivatives* which is given in this case by $Dfv$ (the rate of change of $f$ in the direction of the vector $v$.  This changes from point to point as we move around in $\mathbb{R}^m$, hence the directional derivative...

Comment: @pkumar ... is a function **both** of the position in our space and the direction we may be moving in.  This is illustrated better in non-Euclidean spaces where we can distinguish the actual surface in which we are traversing, and the vectors that point tangent to the surface.  So yes, $Df$ is function of our *position* in our original space, but to find the actual rate of change, we need to pick a specific direction we are moving, hence multiplication by a vector $v$.

Comment: So, what do we infer from this...

Comment: $Df$ is a matrix with variable entries... Which we call it derivative of $f$.. We then fix a vector $v$ and then we have $Df(v)$ which is a matrix with real entries... Then we have $Df(v):\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.. Am i correct? Now, to say some function is continuous, i have to say its domain and range.. To say $Df$ is continuous, i have to say its domain and range... So, domain is $\mathbb{R}^n$ and range is $M_n(\mathbb{R})$...

Comment: @pkumar $Df$ is a matrix with variable entries **corresponding to the position in your original space**.  The notation might be confusing but when I write $Dfv$, I am not evaluating the matrix $Df$ at $v$, I am multiplying $Df$ and $v$ in the sense of matrix multiplication.  To distinguish evaluating the Jacobian at a point, versus finding the directional derivative at a point (or as a function of the original space) I would write $Df|_{(x,y)}$ for the former, and $Dfv$ for the latter.

Comment: We say $g$ is continuous if given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ if $|x-y|<\delta$.. In this case we see that $Df$ is continuous if given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $||Df(x)-Df(y)||<\epsilon$ if $||x-y||<\delta$... When i say $Df(x)$ i mean a matrix and when i say $Df(x)-Df(y)$ i mean difference of matrices and when i say $||Df(x)-Df(y)||$ i mean norm of the matrix... When i say $||x-y||$ i mean norm of the vector $x-y$... Am i correct?

Comment: Ok.. So, we have two different notions.. Now the question that i have in my mind is are these two equivalent.. :O