# How to verify that a function is $C^1$ (continuously differentiable)? Possible connection with component-wise differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a function. We write $f=\left(f_1,\cdots,f_m\right)$, where $f_i:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.

**Original Question :** The problem from which I was motivated to ask this question is the following : Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $f\left(x,y\right)=\left(\cos{x}+\cos{y},\,\sin{x}+\sin{y}\right)$. Is it true that $f \in C^1\left(\mathbb{R}^2\right)?$

The answer is obviously yes! But to establish that, if I understand it correctly, I have to do a hell lot of work. I have to compute jacobian matrix, check continuity of the entries, establish differentiability of $f$ and then check continuity of the total derivative. **I was wondering if there's any easy formulation to verify $C^1$-ness.**

**Question :** I want to know whether or not the following statement holds in general : $f \in C^1\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$ if and only if $f_i \in C^1\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$ for every $i=1,\cdots,n$. If yes, why? If not, is there any such (sufficient) condition at all?

Comment: Yes, your equivalence is true. This follows quite easily from the definition (the Jacobian of $f$ is the Jacobians of $f_1,\dots, f_m$ stacked on top of each other).

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks for the comment! So, can I assume that we only need the entries of the Jacobian $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$ to be $C^1$? (It's probably a very basic question, but I need a confirmation) For example, in the case of the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ mentioned above, I get a nice Jacobian with nice $4$ entries which are all $C^1$. Is it enough to say that $f$ is $C^1$?

Comment: Yes, all you need is that all partial derivatives $\partial f_i /\partial x_j$ exist and are continuous. That this suffices is one of the theorems of multivariable calculus.

Comment: @PhoemueX: These comments together look like an answer; would you mind posting it as one so we can get this off the Unanswered list?

Comment: Dragon, you may also be interested in this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380650/continuously-differentiable-multivariable-functions

Comment: @aleph_two : Thanks!