# Vector-valued continuously differentiable function of several variables is locally Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

My lecture notes on ODEs state the following in the section on unique solutions:

> Definition: Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an interval and let $D
> \subseteq I \times \mathbb{R}^d$ be open. Then $f : D \to
> \mathbb{R}^d$ satisfies a local Lipschitz condition on $D$ if $\forall
> (t_0,y_0) \in D$ there exists a neighbourhood $N(t_0,y_0) \subseteq D$
> of $(t_0,y_0)$ and a constant $L(t_0, y_0) \geq 0$ such that
>
> $\|f(t,y_1) − f(t,y_2)\| \leq L(t_0,y_0) \|y_1 − y_2\|$ for all
> $(t,y_1),(t,y_2) \in N(t_0,y_0)$.
>
> Using the mean value theorem we can show that any function continuousy
> differentiable on $D$ satisfies a local Lipschitz condition by the
> mean value theorem.

In my lecture notes on real analysis the mean value theorem is stated as follows:

> Theorem: Suppose $f : U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable with
> uniformly bounded operator norm $ \|df_x\|_{operator} \leq C$ for
> some $C \geq 0$ and all $x \in U$. Then, for all $a,b$ such that
> $\bar{ab} \in U$
>
> $\|f(b)-f(a)\| \leq \sqrt{n}C \|b-a\|$.

Here $\bar{ab}$ is the segment between $a$ and $b$ and the operator norm for a linear map $L: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n, L(x)=Ax$ is defined as

$\|L\|_{operator}:=\|A\|_{operator}:=sup\{\|L(x)\|=\|Ax\| : \|x\| \leq 1\}$.

Also note that $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

Now I am a bit confused about what it means for a function $f : U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ to be continuously differentiable.

In the single variable real-valued case the derivative is defined through a limit and we can simply define a function $f' : x \to f'(x)$ and call it the derivative. We then say $f$ is continuously differentiable if $f'$ exists and is continuous $\forall x$.

I think in the multivariate vector-valued case we usually consider the partial derivatives and use the same logic, i.e. we say a function $f : U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuously partially differentiable if all partial derivatives exist and are continuous.

But I don't see how I can apply the mean value theorem given this assumption. For this I would need some notion of continuity for the total differential $df_x$, but this is not a real number as in the one-dimension case but a linear map $df_x : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ instead. Do we then say that $f$ is continuously differentiable if the function $df: x \to df_x$ is continuous?

Appreciate it if someone could clarify the definition for me and how we can then show that it implies that $f$ satisfies a local Lipschitz condition.

Thanks very much!

Edit:

Found another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380650/continuously-differentiable-multivariable-functions) that contains an answer to my question. However, would be great if someone could show me why $df: x \to df_x$ is continuous if and only if all partial derivatives are continuous.

Edit 2:

Proof idea:

Since $D$ is open $\exists B_{\epsilon}(t_0,y_0) \subseteq D$. So $\bar{B}_r(t_0,y_0) \subset B_{\epsilon}(t_0,y_0)$ for $0<r<\epsilon$. Now note that $\bar{B}_r(t_0,y_0)$ is closed by definition and bounded since $\bar{B}_r(t_0,y_0) \subset B_{\epsilon}(t_0,y_0)$. So $\bar{B}_r(t_0,y_0)$ is compact.

Since $f$ is continuously differentiable on $N=\bar{B}_r(t_0,y_0)$, we have that $\|df_{(t,y)}\|_{operator}<C$ for all $(t,y) \in N$ by compactness of $N$. So by the mean value theorem

$\|f(t_1,y_1)-f(t_2,y_2)\| \leq \sqrt{n}C\|(t_1,y_1)-(t_2,y_2)\|$ which shows that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on $B_r(t_0,y_0)$ with Lipschitz constant $K=\sqrt{n}C$. In particular, this holds for $t_1=t_2$ which proves the claim.

Note that we have used the convexity of $\bar{B}_r(t_0,y_0)$, see for example [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Open_Ball_is_Convex_Set) (the proof is for the open ball, but the argument is the same.

Comment: Your definition of local lipschitz on $D$ seems incorrect; if anything, what you describe sounds like "Locally Lipschitz in the $y$ variable". Locally Lipschitz on $D$ means the inequality should read: for all $(t_1, y_1), (t_2, y_2) \in N(t_0,y_0)$, we require $ \lVert f(t_1, y_1) - f(t_2, y_2) \rVert \leq L(t_0, y_0) \lVert(t_1 - t_2, y_1 - y_2) \rVert$. Anyway, the theorem you're asking about is a classic theorem of differential calculus. Here's an answer I wrote a while back with a bunch of references and a hint for how to prove it: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3242940/568204

Comment: As a side remark: if you're using the standard Euclidean norm on $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\Bbb{R}^m$, then the $\sqrt{n}$ term is unncecessary in the mean-value inequality. Also, if you take a look at the book by Henri Cartan referenced in my link, you'll also find a much stronger version of the mean-value inequality (whose proof is just as easy/tough as the version you stated)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes, I agree that the condition is different from what one would usually understand as Lipschitz continuity. I think that's why the author says a "Lipschitz condition". I will check out the thread. Regarding the $\sqrt{n}$, it doesn't really matter. Of course you can then just set $D=\sqrt{n}C$. I have simply copied it from my notes and this what comes out of the proof which I have omitted for brevity.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I have edited my answer to include a proof idea I had. Could you please have a look? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly the idea of the proof: pick a small ball with compact closure lying in $D$, then use compactness, and $C^1$-ness to get an upper bound on operator norm then finally use convexity of the ball to apply mean-value theorem. The only real nitpick I have is that in your proof, you never (explicitly) mention what $C$ is. Of course that's an easy fix simply say something like 'by compactness of $N$, there is a $C>0$ such that for all $(t,y) \in N,  \lVert df_{(t,y)} \rVert < C$'

Comment: Thanks, I'll update it later. Did not explicitly write that down since it was obvious to me. Actually, forgot to even think about the convexity of the ball. This is new territory for me since I only learned that stuff a week ago.

Comment: I have updated the proof and also added something regarding the convexity.